# How can I "translate" mmap to the Windows ABI?

Tags: c, windows, closures

I'm currently trying to implement closures in C, following this [wonderful article](https://nullprogram.com/blog/2017/01/08/) from Chris Wellons.
I successfully implemented them on *nix systems, basically copying his article, but I can't seem to make it work on Windows.

The [`closure_create` function](https://nullprogram.com/blog/2017/01/08/#thunk-assembly) is the one giving me troubles. I try to "translate" this:

```c
static void * __closure_create(void *f, int nargs, void *userdata) {
    long page_size = sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE);
    int prot = PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE;
    int flags = MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_PRIVATE;
    char *p = mmap(0, page_size * 2, prot, flags, -1, 0);
    if (p == MAP_FAILED)
        return 0;
    void *closure = p + page_size;
    memcpy(closure, __closure_thunk[nargs - 1], sizeof(__closure_thunk[0]));
    mprotect(closure, page_size, PROT_READ | PROT_EXEC);
    __closure_set_function(closure, f);
    __closure_set_data(closure, userdata);
    return closure;
}
```

to this:

````c
static void * __closure_create(void *f, int nargs, void *userdata) {
    // Memory page size seems to be consistently 0x1000 on Windows
    // If this happens to be wrong, do the following:
    // ```c
    // SYSTEM_INFO info;
    // GetNativeSystemInfo(&info);
    // long page_size = info.dwPageSize;
    // ```
    long page_size = 0x1000;
    DWORD type = MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT;
    char *p = VirtualAlloc(NULL, page_size * 2, type, PAGE_READWRITE);
    if (p == NULL)
        return 0;
    void *closure = p + page_size;
    memcpy(closure, __closure_thunk[nargs - 1], sizeof(__closure_thunk[0]));
    PDWORD lpflOldProtect;
    VirtualProtect(closure, page_size, PAGE_EXECUTE_READ, lpflOldProtect);
    __closure_set_function(closure, f);
    __closure_set_data(closure, userdata);
    return closure;
}
````

Which results in an error message `RUNTIME ERROR: invalid memory access` when calling the closure.

What am I doing wrong ? Is the memory layout different on Windows ?
I tried to run the program using gdb, but the backtrace appears to be useless

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: <program>.exe
[New Thread 7768.0x3764]
[New Thread 7768.0x1858]
[New Thread 7768.0xb40]

Thread 1 received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000021000 in ?? ()
```

I'd appreciate any help to solve this.
Thanks

Comment: Please provide a complete demo. Check the result of `VirtualProtect` for failure. What's the point of allocating two pages and skipping the first?

Comment: A web search of `mmap win32` produces [amongst other links]: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/file-mapping It is a comprehensive tutorial. At the bottom are links to the specific steps needed. You're missing calls to: `CreateFile`, `CreateFileMapping`, `MapViewOfFile`, etc. that are documented in the link. I'd create a function(s) (e.g.) `mymmap` that encapsulates the various steps, possibly with a new `struct` such as `struct mymap` that holds the individual objects that the win32 APIs need/create.

Comment: Thanks for the idea @500-InternalServerError, it was indeed `VirtualProtect` failing with error `Invalid access to memory location`.
I'm trying @CraigEstey solution, thanks for you answer !

Comment: What kind of crazy person would implement closures as fixed 2 memory page blocks allocated with `mmap()`? Even if the waste of memory doesn't bother you, have *some* respect for yourself and use `malloc()` instead.

Comment: From my researches, using `malloc()` to store and execute code is dangerous and not recommended. It appears that it's impossible to change access rights on memory allocated with `malloc()`, which could be dangerous and lead to security issues. If you have other or contradictory information, I'd be glad to ear it and learn more about it  @EOF